# memory leak c++ dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

could you please help me understand the following:

It seems that I have memory leak, and I guess I don't do something correctly with the dynamic array. However I read that I should do delete but it doesn't help. When I print the values, the first 190 are 0 , and some values that don't make sense, and the last 200 values are correct. Here is a part of my code:

At the header file :

```
#define PATH "filespath/"

class Class1
{
public:
    Class1(void);
    ~Class1(void);


    void clean();
    int myfunction(std::string file);
    int SetQC(std::string file);
};
```

While the main cpp file is :

```
Class1::Class1(void)
{
}

Class1::~Class1(void)
{
}

int Class1::myfunction(std::string file) {

    string Logfile;
    bool found = false, SetFound = false;

    Logfile = PATH + file + ".log";
    std::ifstream f;
    std::string line;
    int offset;
    size_t pos;
    int AVGInt = 0, MaxInt = 0, setInt = 0;
    std::string SetVolumeEnd = "keyword"; // test variable to search in file
    int cntProtocol = 0, cntLine = 0, cntAvgTime = 0, cntMaxTime = 0, cntSetTime = 0, cntSetTimeBad = 0;
    int* SetArray = NULL;
    size_t newSizeVolumeSet = 0;
    f.open(Logfile);

    if (!f){
        std::cout << "Unable to open file " << Logfile << " , please check that the path and the filename is correct." << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    else{
        std::cout << "File: " << Logfile << " loaded correctly" << endl;
    }

    if (f.good()){
        while (std::getline(f, line)) { // line is the whole line 
            cntLine++;
                pos = line.find(SetVolumeEnd);
                if (pos != string::npos) // string::npos is returned if string is not found
                {
                    SetFound = false;
                    string SetTime = line.substr(line.length() - 10, 10);
                    pos = SetTime.find("=");
                    string SetTimeExtract = SetTime.substr(pos + 1, SetTime.length() - pos - 3);
                    setInt = stoi(SetTimeExtract);

                    newSizeVolumeSet = cntSetTime + 1;
                    SetArray = new int[newSizeVolumeSet];
                    SetArray[cntSetTime] = setInt;
                    std::cout << "SetArray[" << cntSetTime << "] = <" << SetArray[cntSetTime] << "> ms." << endl;
                    delete[] SetArray;
                    cntSetTime++;
                }
            }
        for (int j = 0; j < cntSetTime; j++){
            cout << j << " element : " << SetArray[j] << endl;
        }
        f.close();
    }

    ofstream set;
    string sett = PATH + file + "set.txt";
    set.open(sett);
    for (int k = 0; k < cntSetTime; k++){
        set << k << " element : " << SetArray[k] << "\n";
    }
    set.close();
    }
```

Comment: You create an array, write a single value to it, and then immediately delete that array again. At the end you write out the values of the array you already deleted, which is undefined behavior. If you didn't delete it, all but the last element in the array would be undefined anyway since you never set them to anything.

This has nothing to do with memory leaks, just whatever your code was supposed to be doing, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Why not just use a `std::vector`?

Comment: hello, thank you for your replies. @cubic, for sure I ' m doing something wrong, my question is what i can do to make it work. I found out that only if I delete the array every time i can print some values in the txt file. I tried to delete it only once at the end, but I receive zeros.

Comment: @jasper, I have seen that some people use vectors, but I would like to se if it can work with an array. thank you

Comment: The problem is that you create a new array every time. Either create one big array at the start, or if you absolutely _have_ to create a new array every time you should copy the old arrays contents into the new one.